# Wait till $http is finished in order to output the result in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

How can I wait with my function till the $http request is finished?

My `services.js` looks as follows:

var app = angular.module('starter.services', []);

```
app.factory('Deals', function($http) {
    function getDeals() {
        $http.get('http://www.domain.com/library/fct.get_deals.php')
        .success(function (data) {
            var deals = data;
            return deals;
        })
        .error(function(err){
      });
  }

  return {
    all: function() {
        return getDeals();
    },
    get: function(keyID) {
        //...
    }
  }
});
```

My `controllers.js` looks like:

```
var app = angular.module('starter.controllers', []);

app.controller('DealCtrl', function($scope, Deals) {
    $scope.deals = Deals.all();
    console.log($scope.deals);
});
```

The `console.log` in my `controllers.js` file outputs "undefined", but when I output the deals in the `getDeals()` function it contains the correct array which I get from my server.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` and all of the async services in angularjs return a `promise` object. See [promise api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api).

You need to use `then` method to assign it to a value in the scope.

So your controller:

```
app.controller('DealCtrl', function($scope, Deals) {
    Deals.all().then(function (deals) {
        $scope.deals = deals;
        console.log($scope.deals);
    });
});
```

Your service

```
app.factory('Deals', function($http) {
    function getDeals() {
        return $http.get('http://www.domain.com/library/fct.get_deals.php')
        .success(function (data) {
            var deals = data;
            return deals;
        });
  }

  return {
    all: function() {
        return getDeals();
    },
    get: function(keyID) {
        //...
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this code throws the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

Comment: @JohnBrunner you need to return the promise to the caller in your service. updated the code

Comment: thank you very much. now i don't get an error, but i have another question. my array from the server looks like `[{id: "1", title: "Title", ...}, ... ]` but I can't access the `title` with `ng-repeat="deal in deals"` and `{{deal.title}}`

Comment: @JohnBrunner Glad I helped. If you think this question has been answered, please mark it so by clicking the check icon near the the answer. However, comments are not the appropriate place to ask follow up questions as it is not useful for future visitors, I suggest you to try to debug it yourself, refer to the official documentation, and if everything else fails, open another question.